# Display a tracking pixel or webbug to Cognito Forms Thank You page

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to display a tracking pixel on the thank you message?

Answer (score 1):

While you can add images to the confirmation message, this will not meet your needs for a tracking pixel, as most browsers pre-load images referenced in markup, even when they are not yet displayed on the page.  We specifically tested this using a Google Analytics tracking pixel and the tracking request occurred as soon as the form was loaded, before the confirmation page was actually displayed.

We are considering adding native support for Google Analytics in the future to allow you to track progress through multi-page forms and the confirmation page.  If this addresses your needs, please up-vote and comment on this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/gZgqqs4g).  If not, please describe the type of tracking you would like to enable.